# Relacionamentos hasOne e belongsTo no mesmo modelo sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Bom estou utilizando `sequelize` juntamente com `nodejs` e estou tendo dificuldades com um relacionamento.

Tenho 3 tabelas onde (local, equipment, shed, area) onde em um local tenho 1 equipamento (equipment), está em um galpão (shed) e pertence a uma área.

As modelos estão assim:

local:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('local', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idEquipment: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idShed: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idArea: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    situation: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        defaultValue: true
    },
    capacity: {
        type: dataTypes.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    posX: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    posY: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    posZ: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    model.belongsTo(models.area, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });

    model.belongsTo(models.equipment, {
        foreignKey: 'idEquipment'
    });

    // model.belongsTo(models.shed, {
    //     foreignKey: 'idShed'
    // });
};

return model;

};[]
```

equipment:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('equipment', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idArea: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    idHangar: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    idControlPlan: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    dateControlPlan: {
        type: dataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    idUserControlPlan: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    model.hasOne(models.local, {
        foreignKey: 'idEquipment'
    });
};

return model;
};
```

shed:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('shed', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    idArea: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    // model.hasOne(models.local, {
    //     foreignKey: 'idShed'
    // });

    model.belongsTo(models.area, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });
};

return model;

};
```

area:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('area', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    model.belongsToMany(models.company, {
        through: 'companyArea',
        foreignKeyConstraint: true,
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });

    model.hasOne(models.shed, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });

    model.hasOne(models.local, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });
};

return model;

};
```

Quando eu adiciono o relacionamento do shed, ele me informa que o não existe relacionamento, quando tiro tudo vai normalmente:

> [SQL Error]
>          SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "public.sheds" does not exist
>          EXIT
>
> [SQL Error]
>          relation "public.sheds" does not exist
>          EXIT

Estou utilizando banco de dados `postgres`.

Onde que pode ser o erro, seria um erro de escrita ? Ou uma modelo não pode ter um relacionamento `belongsTo` e `hasOne` ao mesmo tempo ?

Comment: O erro esta correndo quando você roda a migration ou quando você faz uma consulta ao banco de dados?

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/237720)